# How to suppress warnings in GNU octave

Tags: linux, octave, suppress-warnings

**I am using Octave version 3.4.3, and I get this warning:**

```
warning: fmincg.m: 
possible Matlab-style short-circut operator at line 104, column 20
```

I know why this warning occurs, I just want to make the warning not appear on screen when run.

I know I can suppress ALL warnings by putting this command at the top of my octave program:

```
warning('off','all');
```

Docs: https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/warning.html

But that disables all warnings which is bad form.  How to disable only this one?

Comment: I have added the line 'warning('all','off')' in the header of my Octave function, however when I run my script in batch mode, I still have the warnings. Any workarounds please?

Comment: @Wallflower `warning('off','all');` disables all warnings.  You might have a pre-processing file somewhere countermanding you before the program runs.  Read: https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/warning.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Disable warnings by warning type in GNU Octave:**

See the list of warnings and their warning id's and names here in section: '12.2.2 Enabling and Disabling Warnings'.  https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/warning_ids.html

The warning names and id's are listed with octave command:

```
help warning_ids
```

**Put this command in your octave program before the warning occurs:**

```
warning('off', 'Octave:possible-matlab-short-circuit-operator');
```

**or disable all warnings with**

```
warning('off', 'all');
```

Note: If your warning is thrown by the octave interpreter itself before your script is run, then you'll have to take a different approach.  For example use `octave yourfile.m 2>/dev/null` which also has the unfortunate side effect of redirecting the stderr of both the octave engine and your script.

**Certain warnings terminate the process, and can't be suppressed, they must be remedied:**

Like this one:

```
warning: function /home/el/octave/multicore-0.2.15/gethostname.m 
         shadows a built-in function
```

To fix this, rename /home/el/octave/multicore-0.2.15/gethostname.m to /home/el/octave/multicore-0.2.15/gethostname_backup.m.  And the warning goes away.  It's a bug in the software where two files have the same name, so the program doesn't know which one to use.

Comment: It ís possible to disable that last warning with: `warning('off','Octave:shadowed-function')`. No need to change filenames. The software dóes know which file to use; the first file it finds in its `path`. This is no trickery, it's just overloading functions.

Comment: warning no longer listed at  http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Enabling-and-Disabling-Warnings.html, so useful to know lastwarn (see @Scz answer below)

Answer (score 11):

To find out the ID of your warning, just issue

```
[text, id] = lastwarn()
```

directly after the warning occurs. `id` now contains the id of the warning, which can be used to switch it off:

```
warning('off', id)
```

Comment: Documentation for this function: https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/lastwarn.html

Comment: Essential step for implementing the appropriate command.

Answer (score 4):

Make your changes persistent in two easy steps:

1. become root
2. append command to the file (/usr/share/octave/site/m/startup/octaverc), which will execute any Octave commands at startup.

   `echo "warning('off','Octave:shadowed-function')" >> /usr/share/octave/site/m/startup/octaverc`

I also like to persitantly autoload all packages:

```
echo "pkg load all" >> /usr/share/octave/site/m/startup/octaverc
```

Note: Follow this order, otherwise any shadowed-function warnings you get from loading all packages will still appear.

your file should now contain

```
warning('off','Octave:shadowed-function')
pkg load all
```

Thanks to [Gunther Struyf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1162609/gunther-struyf), for telling us how to turn off shadowed function warnings (above).
Reference: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Octave

Comment: I think you don't need to become root, if you just put the command in `~/.octaverc`.

Comment: @Scz You're right.  Thanks for the note.  To make changes system-wide, use the /usr path above.  To make changes for your user profile only, edit ~/.octaverc